# Error: more than one library with package name 'com.google.android.gms.license'

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

Today, I opened Android Studio, then I get this error. Yesterday, there was a no problem such that!

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
>
> Error: more than one library with package name 'com.google.android.gms.license'

com.google.android.gms:play-services-xxx libraries was

**11.8.0**

Onesignal library was

'com.onesignal:OneSignal:[**3.6.2**, 3.99.99]'

Then I changed them to latest version.

**Now App/Gradle:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "xxx.xxx.xxx"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 10
        versionName 'x.x.x'
        manifestPlaceholders = [onesignal_app_id: "xxxxx-xx-xxx",
                                // Project number pulled from dashboard, local value is ignored.
                                onesignal_google_project_number: "XXX"]

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
}


dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.18'
    compile 'com.github.chrisbanes.photoview:library:1.2.3'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:12.0.0'

    //compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.2.2'

    compile 'com.pkmmte.view:circularimageview:1.1'
    compile 'com.melnykov:floatingactionbutton:1.3.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.5.0'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    //compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:27.1.0'
    compile 'com.balysv:material-ripple:1.0.2'
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:12.0.0"
    compile 'com.github.hotchemi:android-rate:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:[3.7.1, 3.99.99]'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:12.0.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**Project/Gradle:**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'

        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.1'

      //  classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

But I am still getting same error that stated above. How can I solve this problem? Why did this problem occur Today when there was no problem, yesterday?

Comment: Nobody answered. Please answer if you know. Thanks..

Comment: You added same dependency in two places, just as the error says. In top level Project/Gradle and in "module" App ...

Comment: I could not understand your answer, so what should I do?

Comment: Try removing `services` dependencies from Project/Gradle, and adding 
`google()` in Project/Gradle `repositories`.

Answer (score 0):

This probably because the play services version is not in the range defined for 
`OneSignal:[3.7.1, 3.99.99]` which is (you can see it at [this commit](https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-Android-SDK/commit/475038077bd37157c66b194692b2962795077644#diff-45d32610dc0e6adc8d4b28a65a99a165R30)):

```
// Limit upper number (exclusive) to prevent untested versions
static def versionGroupOverrides = [
    'com.google.android.gms': '[10.2.1, 11.7.0)',
    'com.android.support': '[26.0.0, 27.1.0)'
]
```

So, try changing the play services version to `11.7.0`.

You should try using [OneSignal Gradle Plugin](https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-Gradle-Plugin) which helps make the OneSignal Android SDK compatible with your Android Studio project. Use OneSignal-Gradle-Plugin **0.8.0** for `OneSignal:[3.7.1, 3.99.99]`

Comment: Ok but previously com.google.android.gms:play-services-xxx libraries was

11.8.0
Onesignal library was

'com.onesignal:OneSignal:[3.6.2, 3.99.99]'
And there was a no problem.

Comment: Suppose that com.google.android.gms:play-services-xxx libraries was 11.8.0 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:[3.6.2, 3.99.99]' 

Same problem exists. Then I think, my problem is not Onesignal - play-services compability.

Comment: You're probably right about the play services compatibility. Checking this file https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-Android-SDK/blob/ebf0f5940176f8510c3be35f5efa2075a805cdc4/OneSignalSDK/onesignal/maven-push.gradle , it use `'com.google.android.gms': '[10.2.1,11.3.0)',` but as you says, you don't get any error from using play services 11.8.0.

Comment: Is the same error happened if you're using play services 11.8.0 and one signal 3.7.1 ?

Comment: It was 11.8.0 and 3.6.2 and yesterday there was a NO problem. But today suddenly it gave the SAME error. (More info https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/18479
I am not developing in react native but I think the same reason in this link.)
So according to your link(you shared link about compatibility) it seems impossible but I am sure, it was like this. 11.8.0 and 3.6.2 and was working well NOT today, YESTERDAY.